# How do you setup apache to do a reverse proxy from http -> https?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I need to sniff some traffic between VisualStudio and an endpoint for webservices.  I'm not sure how they are sending the username and password with the request for wsdl.

How can you configure Apache to accept a request over http and reverse proxy it out to the real server over https

You end up with an error message like this:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.60.60.6 Port 80
```

I need the traffic from Visual Studio to be in the clear so I can see how they are passing the username/password.  No one on the other end of the API seems to have a clue, they just say use Visual Studio.  This would be fine if our solution was not running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) apache modules in order to be able to proxy SSL requests. First you must have these modules enabled. Then you need to add the SSLProxyEngine, ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse,SSLCAProxyCertificateFile,SSLCAProxyCertificatePath  directives in your virtual host entry.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
     ServerName my.server.name 
     SSLProxyEngine on 
     ProxyPass /secure https://secure.com
     ProxyPassReverse https://secure.com
     SSLCAProxyCertificateFile /path/to/ca_folder/certificate
     SSLProxyCACertificatePath /path/to/ca_folder
</VirtualHost>
```

I have not tested this excact configuration but I think it will work. Please keep in mind that this configuration is not suitable for a public server! Hope that helps!

Comment: This was for development, not debug.